# OutOfMemoryError when parsing large xml file using xstream

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, xstream, unmarshalling

I'm facing a problem while reading large `XML` files "100 MB" and parsing it using `xstream` always the below error occurs

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error occurs,
```

here is the code that parses the XML

> ```
> XStream xstream = new XStream();
> xstream.processAnnotations(Class.forName((String)ClassName));
> ```

ClassName is a normal class that have the fields with xml annotations.

then use

```
Object resultDto = xstream.fromXML((String)fileString);
```

fileString: is the xml file after reading it as inputstream and put it in string buffer.

the above code works fine with small files but didn't work with the big one, any ideas please?

Comment: The XStream constructor can have a parameter with the type of xml parser to use specified, i think, maybe this helps you (not load the whole xml in memory at once): http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

Do not convert your file into a String and then use Xstream, instead use the input stream or file reader directly. `XStream.fromXML` takes various input like File, InputStream, FileReader that operate directly without the need to first loading the text representation of File in memory as String.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are 2 solutions as far as I can see:

1. Increase the heap space.
2. Use a SAX parser instead of a DOM parser (not sure if you can do this with xstream).

Lastly the data might simply be too large to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run your parsing program with runtime parameters?
In that case adding arguments **-xmx512M -xms512M** should do the trick, since it increases the heap size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to incrise your java head memory.
if you are using eclipse.
then there is eclipse,ini file is there,

in that incrise the head size.

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

How much is the RAM size ? If you have more RAM allocate more to your JVM using -

```
Xms512m -Xmx2g -XX:PermSize=512m  -XX:MaxPermSize=2g
```

If you have 8GB of RAM, you could allocate as in the above example it allocate 2GB max Heap memory and 2GB Maximum PermGen space, so in total its 4GB. Or accordingly as per your RAM